# How to get data from 2 tables with one query using mongodb and golang?

Tags: database, mongodb, go, crud, aggregation

I have a TODO list application which is based on items and users. When I get a user from the users collection in mongo, I also want to get the items with the field "userId" which are in another collection. But all this should happen in one query. I want to know how should I emulate the joins from SQL or some method which can return all that I requiring in one query. I only get the id of the user in repository.
Here is the code:
Item

```
type Item struct{
    ItemId      primitive.ObjectID              `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id"`
    Title       string                          `bson:"title,omitempty" json:"title"`
    Description string                          `bson:"description,omitempty" json:"description"`
    UserId      primitive.ObjectID              `bson:"userId" json:"userId"`
}

func NewItem(title string,description string) Item {
    return Item{
        Title:       title,
        Description: description,
    }
}
```

User

```
type User struct{
    UserId primitive.ObjectID               `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"user_id"`
    UserName string                         `bson:"name,omitempty" json:"user_name"`
    Status bool                             `bson:"status" json:"status"`
    Items []Item                            `bson:"items" json:"items"`
}

func NewUser(userId primitive.ObjectID,userName string,status bool,items []Item) User{
    return User{
        userId,
        userName,
        status,
        items,
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use an aggregation with $lookup. It is usually more performant to fetch twice though, once from each collection.

Comment: @BurakSerdar do you have any piece of code or some documents?

Comment: Lookup documentation has examples; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/